# Modifying embedded resource strings from a .net application via another .net application?

Tags: c#, .net, string, resources

Is there a good way to access and possibly modify a resource string inside one compiled .net executable from another .net application?

I searched on Google, but the results I got did not really cover this issue. (they mainly covered handling resources from code, not during runtime)

Edit: To clarify: I have a .net application on my disk (myApp.exe). This application uses a string resource which is embedded in the file via a .resx file. Now from my second application I want to load this exe file, change the string within this resource, and save the exe file.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question and desired result? Are you wanting to get the value of a string object within memory during runtime, modify a hardcoded string value from another application, etc.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code or project of the app you want to load? You could possibly have said app load that string value from a xml file instead of the resource file then just replace the value in the xml file when needed.

Comment: No, there are no "good" ways, only bad ones.

Comment: I do have access to the source, and no I can not have any external files. Hans Passant, that is not very productive.